# Add permissions for TDE templates using ml-gradle

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10, ml-gradle

We are using ml-gradle version 4.1.1 to deploy the XQuery code and data to app-modules database. Now ,we are trying to update the script to deploy TDE templates to app specific Schemas database.

Project path used for templates : /src/main/ml-schemas/tde/sample.tde

And the /tde/ folder have multiple templates in it.

To deploy the templates to App specific Schemas database, I have followed the below steps .

1.Places all the templated under /src/main/ml-schemas/tde/

2.Added `mlSchemasDatabaseName=app-Schemas` and `mlSchemaPaths=src/main/ml-schemas`

3. To add permissions to all the templates, added permission.properties under ml-schemas directory project path

permission.properties content:

`*=ml-admin,read,ml-admin,execute,ml-reader,read`

The TDE templates are getting deployed properly with TDE collection but permissions are not getting added to it.

Can anyone please help me on this to add permissions to the templates?

Comment: Just to confirm - those are valid role names? Everything sounds good - we have a very similar setup on the java-client-api project, though it's for tests so mlSchemaPaths is set to src/test/ml-schemas, but you can see the permissions file at https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/tree/develop/marklogic-client-api/src/test/ml-schemas/tde . Are you able to try the latest ml-gradle release?

Comment: hi @rjrudin , The roles are valid names and the folder structure is similar to that you have shared and I have few queries that I think it may cause the issue , 1. I have sub folders under /tde/ that have the actual TDE templates E.g. /src/main/ml-schemas/tde/example/sample.tde 2.Is there any order preference that we need to follow when providing permissions (read,insert,execute,update,node-update), can we provide it in any order?

Comment: And also I'm using .tde extension for the templates instead of .tdex

Comment: All of that sounds fine, the extension shouldn't matter and the order of roles doesn't matter, as long as you follow the convention of role1,capability1,role2,capability2. Are you able to share a reproducible example of your project, ideally with as few files in it as possible in order to reproduce the problem? If so, file a bug in the ml-gradle github project and include the project files. I am hoping the problem will be easy to spot as this feature is widely used.

Comment: Hi @rjrudin , I have raised a bug in ml-gradle Github project as https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/issues/631 .Please check,thanks in advance!